# (Begin)Invoke with non visual field

Tags: c#, multithreading

Say that Windows Forms application has SomeForm class:

```
public partial class SomeForm : Form
    {
        public int someint;
        ....
    }
```

and one more thread apart from main one. If I want to change form's caption from the other thread I have to use (Begin)Invoke, but do I still have to use it, if I want to access "someint" (which is not related to any visual appearance) ?

If I need so, what happens if "someint" is static field - so it needs no instance of SomeForm to be accessed ?

Comment: The object whose BeginInvoke method you use is not important, all that matters is that it is a control or form object that was also created on the same thread.  You can even use Application.OpenForms[0].BeginInvoke(...).  But since you want to change that form's Text property, you'd better have a good reference to that form object.  So you can use its BeginInvoke() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to `Invoke` things that are related to the UI since it requires everything to happen on its creating thread. You are allowed to access simple fields or properties from other threads without invoking the UI thread.

*However* do note that the compiler and/or JIT may optimize things and assume the values are not changed from other parts of the code. If you need to make sure the values are read and written correctly you may need to use synchronization methods. For example, interlocking, mutexes, volatile and so on.

Comment: Apart from obvious use of mutexes ... I understood that you suggest Invoke in case of "someint" field. If I am correct, is it the same suggestion for static field?

Comment: No, you don’t need Invoke for this field. Only things that require to be used from the creating thread. That’s usually only the UI, very few other things need this. I clarified the sentence